# How do you get the values around the perimeter of a numpy array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array, but I just want the values around the border as a list, as if you were walking around the box perimeter.

To illustrate, for a 2d array, I want to start in one corner and get the values all around the box

[image]

so the result looks like this...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a 2d array called `array`...

```
import numpy as np
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(1,6), range(5))
array=x*y
array[0,0]=999
```

...that looks like this:

```
array([[999,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
       [  2,   4,   6,   8,  10],
       [  3,   6,   9,  12,  15],
       [  4,   8,  12,  16,  20]])
```

we can get the values around the border with some thoughtful slicing...

```
border = []
border += list(array[0, :-1])     # Top row (left to right), not the last element.
border += list(array[:-1, -1])    # Right column (top to bottom), not the last element.
border += list(array[-1, :0:-1])  # Bottom row (right to left), not the last element.
border += list(array[::-1, 0])    # Left column (bottom to top), all elements element.
```

NOTE: We don't want to double-count the corners. That is why we don't include the last element in each row/column slice. However, in that last statement, we include the last element to close the path.

The value of `border`:

```
array([999,   0,   0,   0,   0,   5,  10,  15,  20,  16,  12,   8,   4,
         3,   2,   1, 999])
```

---

I turned this into a function that allows you to specify which corner to start at and to walk around the array either counter-clockwise or clockwise (https://gist.github.com/blaylockbk/a70537b41050d1d761ab6c5ab6e4bd43)